# Why $d\langle X \rangle_t = d X_t dX_t$ if $X_t$ is a semimartingale?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Following [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1614610/how-can-i-prove-the-equivalence-of-these-two-itos-lemma-notations) question, proving the equivalence between equation $(1)$ and $(2)$, I deduced that $$d\langle X \rangle_t = d X_t dX_t$$ (where $X_t$ was an Ito's process, hence a semimartingale).

I would like to discover why the equation above holds.

Comment: How do you define (rigorously) the right-hand side? See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/81865/).

Comment: @saz I'm not a mathematician (as you may have noticed), so I don't know how rigorous this is, but I took the definition of $dX_t$ as an Ito's drift-diffusion process ($dX_t =  \mu(t, X_t)dt + \sigma(t, X_t) \, dW_t $) and I squared it. From there I proceeded as shown in the question in your link. But even if the equation in my question seems intuitively right, I can't understand the mathematical steps to prove it

Comment: The point is that you can't simply multiply/square differentials. As discussed in the linked question, statements like $$dB_t \, dB_t = dt$$ are just rules to simplify calculations.

Comment: @saz Can I write the following?
$\langle X \rangle_t $ is by definition $\int_0^t \sigma^2_s d_s = \sigma^2 dt$ and $d X^2_t = dX_td X_t=(\mu dt + \sigma d W_t)^2= \sigma^2 dt$. Then, $ d \langle X \rangle_t = d X_t d X_t $

Comment: Obviously you can write it, but it is not mathematically rigorous (because you are using rules which are not rigorous, see my previous comment).